# Is it possible to create a Windows Phone live tile where no title is displayed?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I've got a background image which contains the title of my application already. I don't want to display the Windows Phone title on the tile -- because displaying it there covers up the content I want to show.

Several Windows Phone applications, such as Office, don't display any title at all on their live tile. But if you try to enter a blank name for the live tile, Visual Studio complains at you.... forcefully.

Is not showing a separate title layer something that's only available to Microsoft or something like that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [this thread](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/73165.aspx).

I haven't used it before, but the person who posted the solution says it worked and got approved for the Marketplace.

> In WMAppManifest.xml file in the 'Properties' folder of the project, replace the contents of the  element of  with 2 or 3 spaces. This compiles without errors and displays without the app's name in the 'Start' page when you pin it.

```
<TemplateType5>  
    <BackgroundImageURI ... ... ...>Background.png</BackgroundImageURI>  
    <Count>0</Count>  
    <Title>   </Title>  
</TemplateType5>
```

Comment: You don't even have to enter spaces. You just have to edit the XML file directly. Visual Studio thinks this field cannot be empty but it can.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the tiles a blank title. I do this frequently for my apps, and many popular apps such as the Amazon Kindle app do this too.

Although this can't be done directly in the 'property editing' mode of the project, you can edit the WMAppManifest.xml directly and you will be able to remove the title. To do this, simply remove the title between the  tags and the project will still compile. See the XML below (I have omitted a chunk of the XML for conciseness):

```
    ...

          <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Background.png</BackgroundImageURI>
          <Count>0</Count>
          <Title></Title> <-- This is the element you need to leave blank
        </TemplateType5>
      </PrimaryToken>
    </Tokens>
  </App>
</Deployment>
```

Answer (score -1):

Put a full stop in as the title. Bit of a cheat but looks OK.

Comment: This looks really bad depending on the background image.