# Universal App On Phone - How to hide DisplayName?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

When I run my Windows Universal App on my Windows 8.1 phone, the LiveTile has additional text (the name of my app) on it that I'm trying to hide.  The text seems to be coming from the Package.appxmanifest

```
<m3:VisualElements DisplayName="This Text Appears" ...
```

I found a similar question ([Is it possible to create a Windows Phone live tile where no title is displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762652/is-it-possible-to-create-a-windows-phone-live-tile-where-no-title-is-displayed)) that suggests leaving the value empty.  When I do this, Visual Studio complains that it is invalid and I'm not able to compile.  Removing the DisplayName entirely also results in an error.

I can see other applications that do not show any text, so it does seem possible.

Can anyone tell me how to hide the DisplayText from my LiveTile, but still have the name of my app appear correctly on the list of installed apps on the phone?

The template I'm using for the live tile (TileWide310x150Image).

Comment: Have you tried to set it to a blank " "?

Comment: @RicoSuter - I get an error message saying The 'DisplayName' attribute is invalid - The value ' ' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest:ST_DisplayName' - The Pattern constraint failed.'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove the App name from my flipping live tile on Windows Phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078543/how-do-i-remove-the-app-name-from-my-flipping-live-tile-on-windows-phone)

Answer (score 1):

The DisplayName attribute inside the **Package.appxmanifest** file is required and cannot be left blank.  It's also the name that will show in the Phone's list of installed Apps.  You want that be the proper name of your app.

The name of the app will appear on the LiveTile and, in that context, it's called 'Branding'.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212854.aspx

```
 <binding template       = tileTemplateNameV2
          fallback?      = tileTemplateNameV1
          lang?          = string
          baseUri?       = anyURI
          branding?      = "none" | "logo" | "name"
          addImageQuery? = boolean
          contentId?     = string >
```

It seems to default to 'name', but by setting it to 'none' the text will no longer be displayed on the live tile.

Comment: And then how you set in the Package.appxmanifest that kind of branding, it is an attribute? I do not understand

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the Wide Tile Display Name in a Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime C# Application with the following code:

```
        XmlDocument squareTileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWide310x150PeekImage04);
        XmlNodeList brandAttribute = squareTileXml.GetElementsByTagName("binding");
        ((XmlElement)brandAttribute[0]).SetAttribute("branding", "none");
```

*squareTileXml* is the name of the XML being configured  to the Live Tile while *TileWide310x150PeekImage04* is the chosen template.

Basically I specified a tile template ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tiletemplatetype.aspx)) and I changed the property branding, which is inside the binding in the XML tree, according to this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212854.aspx), to none, removing the Display Name.

I'm not sure if this is the right way of configuring that, but at least it worked.